# Keyboard will not work after install ubuntu 15.10

Tags: usb, keyboard

I am very new to linux and installed ubuntu on for my grandparents new computer, but the USB keyboard will not work on the login screen. Not even any lights for num lock, caps lock, scroll lock, etc. I can use the onscreen keyboard to access the terminal but nothing has worked for me so far. Help?

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port?

Comment: Does your keyboard get listed by running `lusb` in a terminal?